# Video capture in seaside smalltalk

Tags: video-capture, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm developing a smalltalk application with the pharo seaside framework where I need to access the camera to capture images and video

How can i start a video capture in this framework?

I'll be waiting for an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html5 input capture feature is not supported in most browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture

Since Seaside is a server-side web application framework, you will need to look at client-side (Javascript) libraries to perform video capture in web applications.

If the html5 input capture feature is what you are looking for, something like this should work:

```
html fileUpload
    attributeAt: 'accept' put:'video/*'; 
    attributeAt: 'capture' put:true;
    callback: [:file | ... ]
```